# nodejs res.download() file

Tags: javascript, node.js

i'm pretty new to nodejs and stuff, and i;ve been researching on how to upload and download a file from a nodejs server

the upload part works just fine, the problem is the download part

the code i wrote has no errors but however, the file itself is not downloading, i have no idea where i went wrong

here's my uploadss.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var multer  =   require('multer');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');  

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

var storage =   multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, __dirname + '/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});
var upload = multer({ storage : storage }).array('userPhoto',5);


app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.get('/index', function(req, res){
  res.render('indexss.ejs');
});

app.use('/', router);

app.post('/api/photo', function(req, res){
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
         if(err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        res.end("File is uploaded");
    });
});

router.get('/download', function(req, res) { 
  var dir = path.resolve(".") + '/uploads/';
  fs.readdir(dir, function(err, list) { 
    if (err) 
      return res.json(err);
    else
      res.json(list);
  });

});

router.get('/download/:file(*)', function(req, res, next){ 
  var file = req.params.file;
  var path = require('path');
  var path = path.resolve(".") + '/uploads/' + file;
  res.download(path, file, function(err){
    if (err){
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log('downloading successful');
    }
  });
});


app.listen(8080);
```

and here's the indexss.ejs file that contains the html and javascript

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.form/3.51/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#uploadForm').submit(function() {
                $("#status").empty().text("File is uploading...");
                $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                        status('Error: ' + xhr.status);
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#status").empty().text(response);
                        console.log(response)
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }); 


            $.ajax({
                url: "/download",
                method: "get",
                success: function(data){
                    downloadArray = data;
                    for (i = 0; i < downloadArray.length; i++){
                        console.log(downloadArray[i]);
                        console.log(typeof downloadArray[i]);
                        $('#downloadList').append("<a href='#' onclick='downloadFile(this)'>" + downloadArray[i] + "</a><br>");

                    }
                }
            });
        });
        function downloadFile(selectedFile){
            fileToDownload = $(selectedFile).text();
            console.log(fileToDownload);
            $.ajax({
                url: "/download/" + fileToDownload,
                method: "get",
                success: function(){
                    console.log('successful downloading');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>  
</head>

<body>

    <form id="uploadForm"
        enctype="multipart/form-data"
        action="/api/photo"
        method="post">
        <input type="file" name="userPhoto" multiple />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
        <input type='text' id='random' name='random'><br>
        <span id = "status"></span>
    </form>

    <div id='downloadList'></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you're facing the issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax).

Comment: i think that is way of my issue

Comment: can you share the error log while you are making call to download file link? also, please share the file structure snapshot, it might be the issue with the path

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding path with filename parameter. Try this:

```
res.download(path);
```

And read **res.download(path [, filename] [, fn])** at: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: that was the first thing i tried, then i switch to the code i posted. And i've already read that one. it's my primary resource site

Answer (score 0):

try the following code

**server**

```
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
app.get('/image', function (req, res) {
    var path_image = req.headers.path;
    var src = fs.createReadStream(path_image);
    src.on('open', function () {
        src.pipe(res);
        log.info('down completed: ' + path_image);
    });
    src.on('error', function (err) {
        log.error('' + err);
    });
});
```

**path_image** is your file path, i use the client-side information sent

**java-client** use library https://github.com/koush/ion

```
Ion.with(MainActivity.this)
    .load("http://IP:PORT/image")
    .setHeader("path", path_image_on_server)
    .progress(new ProgressCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(long downloaded, long total) {
            Log.e("bc", "" + downloaded + " / " + total);
        }
    })
    .write(new File(path_image_save_file))
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<File>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, File file) {
            if (e != null) {
                Log.e("bc", e.toString());
            }
            if (file != null) {
                Log.e("bc", file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
       }
   });
```